# interpolation across 6-D data, using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, spatial-interpolation

I am attempting to interpolate across a 6-dimensional, non-monotonic, real domain. I'm using MATLAB. I am pretty sure that the function "griddatan" will do, but when I try to run it, I get the following error  from one of its subroutines:
"Error using qhullmx
The data is degenerate in at least one dimension - ND set of points lying in (N+1)D
space."

However, all of my input matrices comply with the documentation and are not dimensionally-degenerate.

Anyone ever had this problem? 
I'm sorry I can't provide much more context. If you know of any other way to interpolate ungridded 6D data, please let me know!

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: is your data of class `integer` ?